# Kill a specific PHP script running on FastCGI / IIS?

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

I'm a PHP developer, but honestly my knowledge of server management is somewhat lacking.

I fired off a script today that took a regrettably long time to run, and because it had an embedded call to `ignore_user_abort()`, pressing "stop" in the browser was obviously futile.

There was a time limit of 15 minutes enforced in the FastCGI settings, but this was still incessantly long since I really had to just wait it out before I could continue with anything else.

Is there some way to manage/kill whatever PHP scripts are being executed by FastCGI at any given moment?

Answer (score 1):

Does the php process appear in the taskmanager?
I wonder what happens if you kill it there. Will the IIS start another one to handle the next request?

Comment: Sometimes it will, but often it won't.